# MobaXterm Execute Command

Tags: unix, mobaxterm

To connect from windows desktop to unix host, in order of administration on command line level, I like to use MobaXterm in it's free version 
The connection is encrypted ssh, identification to Unix host is using user id, passwd.
There is an issue in I can't resolve:
In the "Session Settings" is a field "Execute Command".
This command there is supposed to be executed in the target host when login has been successful finished. The hosts I have to use are may be not the fastest - Or MobaXterm is too fast.
However, the command is issued in a to early stage, the host feels mortally offended, closes connection and throws me out.
It does not matter what the command is - even a sleep is not accepted.

How to tell MobaXterm to act a bit slower?

Answer (score 6):

**MobaXterm** default behavior for executing a command is to close the session after execution.

To prevent that there is a setting near the **"Execute command"** field that states: `"Do not exit after command ends"`. Just check that and it will fix the problem.